# Difference betwee destroy and delete_doc in couchrest

Tags: ruby, couchdb, couchrest

I've been trying to delete docs in couchdb (using ruby couchrest) to recover disk space.  I realize that [deleting](http://rubydoc.info/github/couchrest/couchrest/CouchRest/Database#delete_doc-instance_method) docs may not free up space.  I then used Document::[destroy](http://rubydoc.info/github/couchrest/couchrest/CouchRest/Document%3adestroy) (it sounded like it would work).  After compacting views it seemed like it freed up much more than it should.

Can you explain what destroy does?  Do you know why I recovered so much space?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source it seems that both methods do more or less the same (destroy even calls `delete_doc()`). The only difference seems to be that `destroy()` also removes the `_id` and `_rev` fields from the local object, which makes no difference on the server side.

It seems, though, that both methods do some kind of batching (when passing `bulk = true`). So it might be the case that your calls to `delete_doc()` where cached and your subsequent calls to `destroy()` simply exceeded the limit and executed the bulk deletion on the server.

Comment: let me check and get back.  I get the impression from various articles that even if you delete docs you can't claim the diskspace back from couchdb.  do you know if that is true

Comment: That's partially correct. You can delete a doc by simply adding a ``_deleted: true`` attribute to it. In that case the doc is considered deleted but all its other properties will remain intact and it will still consume its full disk space. You can use that for example to store why a document has been deleted. Alternatively you can use the HTTP method DELETE which will remove all attributes and add the delete flag. In that case most of the space will be freed when compacting the database, but a small "doc tombstone" will always be left behind.